# Spectrum of the projection of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projection-matrices

Let $A$ be a strictly positive symmetric matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $P$ be an orthogonal projection onto a subspace $U$ of dimension $m \leq n$.

Is there any way to relate the eigenvalues (and/or eigenvectors) of the projected matrix $PAP$ to the matrix $A$?

My end goal is to find a bound (if possible) on $\|(PAP+ \lambda)^{-1/2}(A+\lambda)^{1/2}\|$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm and $\lambda > 0$.

Any pointer/reference welcome.

Comment: Are you talking about orthogonal projections?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have modified my question.

Comment: Something doesn't sound right: if $P$ is not the identity matrix, it must be singular and $(PAP)^{-1/2}$ does not exist.

Comment: Yes in my application I have an additional term on the diagonal, I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality we assume that the subspace is $R^m$. As a consequence, by blocks:
$$PAP=\left[\begin{array}{cc}I_m&0\\0&0\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc}A_1&A_{12}\\A_{21}&A_2\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc}I_m&0\\0&0\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc}A_1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right].$$ Suppose that $m=n-1$ and that the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A_1$ are respectively
$$\lambda_1\leq\ldots\leq\lambda_n,\ \mu_1\leq\ldots\leq \mu_{n-1}.$$ Then $$\lambda_1\leq
\mu_1\leq \lambda_2\leq \mu_2\leq\ldots\leq \mu_{n-1}\leq\lambda_n.$$ The proof is a bit long to be given here but is found in the good books of linear algebra.

Well, if $m$ is $n-2$ or smaller, you have to iterate this result, and the location of the eigenvalues of $A_1$ will be less and less precise when $m$ decreases.

Comment: This is nice. Could you point me to one of "the good books of linear algebra"?

Comment: For instance Horn and Johnson 'Matrix Analysis' page 183 (not very elegant proof to my taste).